# Is it possible to send data from a server to a gprs module without it opens a connection first?

Tags: networking, gprs, iot

If not, what is the best way to deal with the fact that the module needs to open a connection first?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Three typical solutions:

1. Module opens connection at startup and keeps it open forever. (long polling)
2. Module asks server periodically (short polling)
3. Server wakes-up Modem using a dummy SMS or dummy voice call.

For option 3, make sure that the SMS is only used for waking-up. Do not send information in the SMS, as SMS is nowadays insecure.